# In Visual Studio , Why does the C Program running in Debug mode ,is not running in Runtime

Tags: c, runtime

I am new to Visual Studio tool.The program is compiled successfully and the method Multiplication is called succesfully in debugging mode,whereas it is not getting executed in run time .

Here is my code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int Splitting(int *, int);
    int Multiplication1(int, int, int, int);

   int main()
    {
        int x1 = 1234567891, y1 = 567891, x = x1, y = y1, a1, b1, c1, d1, count = 0, Answer = 0;
               while (x1 % 10 != 0)
                     {
                      x1 = x1 / 10;//1
                      count++;//3
                     }
        x1 = x;
        printf("count=%d", count);
        a1 = Splitting(&x, count);
        b1 = x;
        printf("a1=%d,b1=%d\n", a1, b1);
        //  printf("a1=%d,b1=%d\n", a1,b1);
        count = 0;
                 while (y1 % 10 != 0)
                       {
                       y1 = y1 / 10;
                       count++;
                       }
        y1 = y;
        c1 = Splitting(&y, count);
        d1 = y;
        printf("a1=%d,b1=%d,c1=%d,d1=%d\n", a1, b1, c1, d1);
        Answer = Multiplication1(a1, b1, c1, d1);
        printf("Answer=%d\n", Answer);
        return 0;
    }
    int Splitting(int *x, int count)
    {
        int x1 = *x, x2, a = 0, b = 0, a1 = 0, b1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0;i < count / 2;i++)//0,1
            {
            a = x1 % 10;//4,3
            x2 = x1 / pow(10, count / 2);//12345
            b = x2 % 10;//6
            x1 = x1 / 10;//123,
            x2 = x2 / 10;
            a1 += a * pow(10, i);//4+30=34,
            b1 += b* pow(10, i);//=>12*
            }
        printf("Splitting,a1=%d,b1=%d\n", a1, b1);
        *x = a1;
        return b1;
    }
    int Multiplication1(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        printf("Inside Multiplication function");
        printf("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d,d=%d", a, b, c, d);
        unsigned long step1, step2, step3, step4, Answer;
        Answer = a+b+c+d;
        printf("Answer=%d\n", Answer);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i wrote that Comments inorder to make people understand about the logic used.sorry i missed to close it.But the problem still exsists.

Comment: `Answer = Multiplication1(a1, b1, c1, d1);` : `c1` and `d1` are not initialized.

Comment: is the math.h header file really have a capital letter 'M'?   Everywhere I have ever used it (most recently on Linux but plenty before on Windows) the header file was all lower case.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Inorder to reduce the post content i didnt include (i have mentioned in comment c1=567,d1=891)  c1 & d1 to get values .They will use the same logic of how a1 &b1 will get values.

Comment: @user3629249 sir , in Visual Studio it is compiling and executing with Math.h & math.h ,It doesn't affect the products ouptut

Comment: So, Do you have reproducibility in this code? also try `pow(10., ...`

Comment: if you enable all the compiler warnings, when compiling, the compiler would tell you (at least) three things.  1) line 17 warning: 'd1' is used uninitialized in this function  2) line 17 warning: 'c1' is used uninitialized in this function  3) line 8 warning: unused variable 'y1'    Of these 3 items, the first two are critical.  after fixing the problems, please re-post the code.

Comment: You ask about a runtime problem.  Therefore, the posted code needs to compile cleanly and still display the problem.   Otherwise we can only guess about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Probably it has caused a memory overwrite in my opinion.

Comment: @user3629249  sir ,i have posted my entire code .It doesn't have any compiler warnings.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I hope it can't be Memory overwrite,Its running succesfully in Debug mode,Only problem is while executing in Runtime. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `printf("Answer=%d\n", Answer);` should be `printf("Answer=%lu\n", Answer);`

Comment: given this line:  `int x1=1234567891,y1=567891,a1, b1, c1, d1,x=x1,count = 0, Answer = 0;`  1) there is no guarantee as to the order of evaluation of the comma separated expressions.  2) Strongly suggest only 1 variable declaration per statement line.  this will greatly assist with readability/understandability by us humans. this will make documentation much easier (which in the real world is almost always required)  3) separate code blocks via a blank line, again, so us humans can easily read/understand the code

Comment: @user3629249 tanx for the info.I will Correct it from next time and hope this will help me to improve my skills

Comment: @BLUEPIXY tats an error on my side,but the main problem is Multiplication  function is itself not getting invoked

Comment: it's undefined behavior. I will leave.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sir, whether the program is not clear or the reason for the problem is not clear ?

Comment: Was called when I tried on VS 2010. (Although it required edit for non-C location of declaration)

Comment: @mksteve i ran the program in VS 2015.The problem occured in it.

Comment: the two printf() statements in the Multiplication function need to have '\n' appended to the format strings so they will print properly

Comment: @user3629249 tanx for the info

Comment: the Multiplication1() function always returns 0 so `Answer` will always contain 0

Comment: What is giving you the idea the that Multiplication1() function is not being properly called?

Comment: @user3629249 as the Multiplication function is not getting executed ,i just changed the return value from original answer to 0, to make sure that the problem was not due to it.

Comment: @user3629249 In Multiplication1() function, in line 1 it contains print statement to print a string, even that is not getting printed